# Suppress compiler warning for specific template code

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, type-conversion, compiler-warnings

I have implemented a template class to detect the convertability of two type (following the method described in the book Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu Section 2.7).

The implementation I made is as follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
class Conversion
{
private:
    using Small = char;
    using Big = class{ char dummy[2]; };
    static Small Test(U);
    static Big Test(...);
public:
    enum
    {
        exists = (sizeof(Test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(Small)) // Warning related to conversion.
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Conversion int to float :" << Conversion<int, float>::exists << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling this code on **Visual Studio 2013**(**Visual C++ 2013**), I get following warning related to conversion from int to float

> warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible
>   loss of data.

As it was an implicit requirement here, is there a way to suppress this warning?

I just want to suppress it for this case alone. If such conversion is being done in other places, compiler should still generate the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that if someone has an urge to suppress a /correct/ warning then he is most likely doing something wrong. In this case tester can be rewritten to perform `explicit` conversion. This will also allow it to handle user-defined `explicit` conversion operators (that are not covered by your original code or `::std::is_convertible`):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Anything> class
Void
{
    public: using type = void;
};

template<typename T, typename U, typename Enabled = void> class
Conversion
: public ::std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename U> class
Conversion<T, U, typename Void<decltype(static_cast<U>(::std::declval<T>()))>::type>
: public ::std::true_type {};

struct foo{ explicit operator int(void) const; };

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << "Conversion short to int :" << Conversion<short, int>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion int to short :" << Conversion<int, short>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion int to float :" << Conversion<int, float>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion float to int :" << Conversion<float, int>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion float to foo :" << Conversion<float, foo>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion foo to float :" << Conversion<foo, float>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion int to foo   :" << Conversion<int, foo>::value << "\n";
    ::std::cout << "Conversion foo to int   :" << Conversion<foo, int>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fVo51ojDnD7xt6C0), [no error with /W4 on vc++](https://godbolt.org/g/J3gXMr)

Comment: I just need to make sure that I understand the code right. Here, if the types are actually convertible, we go for the specialized template. If they are not, (as per SFINAE) we go for the base template.
And since we are using static_cast, it takes care of implicit conversions and explicit user defined conversions, right?

Comment: One particular case that was discussed in the book was calling conversion on std::size_t and std::vector. This fails even though vector has a constructor that takes std::size_t, as the constructor is declared explicit. With your code this conversion still fails. Is it because static_cast only work for implicit and user-defined conversions?

Comment: @sajas But [It does not fail with my code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ppj3Iu5hILbwa8Bk).

Comment: @sajas Again, my code correctly does not fail in this case and reports `true` if conversion is possible though an `explicit` user-defined constructor. `static_cast` does take into account explicit user-defined constructors as defined in `15.3.1 Conversion by constructor [class.conv.ctor]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#pragma warning(suppress, …`, as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: Just wanted to mention that you probably should put the suppress into `#pragma warning(push)` and `#pragma warning(pop)`

Comment: `suppress` is a combination of `push` → `disable` → `pop`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember that. It's some time since I used MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `std::is_convertible` in C++11:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
class Conversion
{
private:
    using Small = char;
    using Big = class{ char dummy[2]; };
    static Small Test(U);
    static Big Test(...);
public:
    enum
    {
        exists = (sizeof(Test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(Small)) // Warning related to conversion.
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Conversion int to float :" << Conversion<int, float>::exists << "\n";
    std::cout << "Conversion int to float :" << Conversion<float, int>::exists << "\n";

    std::cout << "Conversion int to float :" << std::is_convertible<int,float>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "Conversion int to float :" << std::is_convertible<float, int>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I don't have a local Visual C++ here, [but the online compiler does not generate a warning for `std::is_convertible` with warning level 4:](http://rextester.com/TAR40540)

```
Warning(s):
source_file.cpp(15): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'std::ios_base::iostate' to 'float', possible loss of data
source_file.cpp(21): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Conversion<int,float>' being compiled
source_file.cpp(15): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
source_file.cpp(22): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Conversion<float,int>' being compiled
/LIBPATH:C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib 
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64
Conversion int to float :1
Conversion int to float :1
Conversion int to float :1
Conversion int to float :1
```

Comment: I was more interested in bringing that behavior to my Conversion class. Thanks for the information.